# 4-pin challenge: defeat BIOS controller on 5.3A fans

Tags: bios, fan

Background:
I have a beast of a server chassis from SuperMicro that I got cheaply.  It holds 90 hard drives, and to cool it, uses 5 counter-axial fans.  That means it technically powers 10x 76db, 5.3A fans.  The 5 paired "sets" deliver 136CFM and 76db, making it 85db at 1m away.  Fan is SC FAN-0161L4 for the curious.

Chassis is "dumb" with no CPU / only IPMI-based BIOS control.  BIOS will not let the fans go below 8500 rpm, at which they are still "very loud".   No way (yet) to hack the BIOS.

I took it apart.  The power bus supplies power to 10x 4-pin fan controllers that are standard 4-pin Molex.

Question:   how do I defeat the BIOS control and reduce voltage to these fans to let them spin more quietly?

Yes that will heat up the case, but I'm going to test the heck out of this before I deploy.

Question2: I'm worried that the 4-pin "sense" wire, if it passes back through a voltage reducer, will report a low speed and motivate the BIOS to ramp voltage.  How do I overcome that?

Comment: This might be more suited tot the Electrical Engineering StackExchange site.

Comment: You may well be right on that, Tonny -- thx.  I will wait a bit here to see if anything else comes through.  If not, I'll delete this and re-post there.